# There is a 4px gap below canvas/video/audio elements in HTML5

Tags: css, html, canvas

When using HTML5, if you place a `canvas`/`video`/`audio`/`svg` element in a `div`, there will be a `4px` gap below these elements. I tested the code below in almost all browsers which support HTML5, unfortunately they all have the same problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bug</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue">
<canvas width="200" height="100" style="border: 1px solid yellow"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's because they are inline elements with resizable `height` (most `inline` elements are not explicitly resizable). If you set them to `display: block;` the gap goes away. You can also set `vertical-align: top;` to achieve the same result.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/F2LAK/

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <canvas width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="block" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

canvas {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#block {
    display: block;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! But if set to {display: inline-block}, the gap appears again. Why the behavior of these elements is different to other inline elements?

Comment: `img` works the same way. It's `inline` elements that have resizable `height`. `vertical-align: top;` fixes the problem if you want to keep the element `inline`.

Comment: {vertical-align: top;} This is really what I want! You are so great!

Comment: `vertical-align:top` worked for me in Chrome! That gap was aggravating.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone wondering what the gap actually is:

As ThinkingStiff mentions, these are inline elements. That means that by default they will try to align themselves with the baseline of text. If you had some adjacent text, it would be easier to see what's happening.

The amount of space left below the svg is the size of a descender at the current font-size. This is why Teg's solution only works for the default font-size. The default font-size is 16px and 4px of that is dedicated to the descender. If you increase the font-size, the descender will also increase.

See the same piece of DOM using font-sizes of default (16px), 50px and 0px;

```css
div{
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
canvas{
   border: 1px solid red;
}
#two{
   font-size:50px;
}
#three{
   font-size:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
    xy<canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="two">
    xy<canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="three">
    xy<canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: great explanation

Comment: Thank you for getting to the cause of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Margin -5px is working in Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bug</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue">
<canvas width="200" height="100" style="border: 1px solid yellow; margin-bottom:-5px"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wonder why all browsers have the similar problem? I can't find any default styles about that.

Comment: Note, that it's 5px in this case because you have set up a border with 1px thickness, so if you remove the border, it's only 4px. Anyway, that solution seems to be kind of dirty, I like the vertical-align:top; - method in the accepted answer more :).

Comment: See my answer for [why all browsers have this "problem" and why this fix only work for default font sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59086256/514793).