# Fully responsive HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

Is it possible to have a HTML5 in an absolutely positioned `<video>` element that resizes to the window width and height so that nothing is ever cropped? Lots of the solutions I've seen seem to rely on the `<iframe>` tag, which I don't have, or only resize based on width (which I can already do).

Basically I'm looking for a way to ensure the video is as big as it can be, but also never get cropped if the window is resized -- even in IE9. (Note: I the video has to retain its ratio -- so it's OK if there's black bars.)

This is what I have tried so far.

```css
/*CSS*/

#player-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000        
    z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<div id="player-overlay">
  <video width="100%" video="100%" style="width:100%, height:100%">
    <source src="../static/video/10s.mp4" />
    <source src="../static/video/10s.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
    <source src="../static/video/10s.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
  </video>    
</div>
```

It seems to me that I'm going to have try and write a JS solution instead.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php -- second result on a Google search.

Comment: This works great these days: http://embedresponsively.com/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `width` and `max-height` on the `<video>` element:

```
<div id="player-overlay">
    <video>
        <source src="../static/video/10s.mp4" />
        <source src="../static/video/10s.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
        <source src="../static/video/10s.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
    </video>    
</div>
```

```css
video {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fHG69/

Also, you're missing a semicolon after `background-color`.  When absolutely positioning an element to fill the screen, I prefer to set `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` instead of setting `height` and `width`.

Answer (score 15):

(I know this is an old thread, but I hope my answer helps someone out there.)

Actually, you had the correct solution already. The `style="width:100%, height:100%"` on your `<video>` works, except you need a semicolon there instead of a comma. (You can remove the redundant `width="100%"` and `video="100%"` attributes.)

The reason that `width: 100%; height: 100%` works (note the semicolon) is that, even though the `<video>` element is stretched, the video itself keeps its aspect ratio and is letterboxed/pillarboxed inside the `<video>` element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4000946/5249519 .

The advantage of `height: 100%` is that the video is letterboxed exactly in the center, whereas with `max-height: 100%` the video is aligned to the top of the container.

Also, you should set your `<video>` to `display: block`. Otherwise, it defaults to `display: inline` and you'll get some white space at the bottom of the video for the font descenders: [There is a 4px gap below canvas/video/audio elements in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8600393/5249519) .

Finally, like @gilly3 said, you need a semicolon after `background-color: #000`. And, of course, you need to remove `display: none`. =)

Here's the full solution:

```css
/*CSS*/

#player-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 999;
}

video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<div id="player-overlay">
  <video controls>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv"  type="video/ogg">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp"  type="video/3gp">
  </video>
</div>
```

Run the code snippet in "full page" mode and resize your browser window to see the letterboxing effect.

By the way, your video sources weren't working anymore, so I used sample videos from: http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5 .

Hope that helps.

Comment: This works well except when in a responsive condition like Bootstrap moves to a single column. At that point the height became 1px so I would suggest at least some minimum height in the #player-overlay style. For instance; min-height:200px;

Answer (score 2):

You should use this CSS for the proper solution-
If you use `height: auto;` It'll cover your container.

```
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this answer while trying to find something else on responsive videos. I implemented a responsive video element using similar code.

This link may help make sense of some things
[Height equals width Pure CSS](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html#outer_wrap)

Your code could look like this:

```
#player-overlay {
  position: relative;

  &:before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 50%;  // 50% equals a 2:1 ratio. you can read more about
                       // the ratios in the link
  }
}

video {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can change the ratio by simply changing the padding-top on the before pseudo element.