# How to make my video responsive in website ? [html]

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design

Is there any way to make a video in `<video>` tag mobile responsive ?

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="rick.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<style>
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> ?

Comment: I tried this but no change ..

Comment: Do you want to cover the entire screen ?

Comment: Refer this Question, I hope this question will giv some idea to you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796799/fully-responsive-html5-video

Answer (score 1):

Please check, I have did Video responsive in following ways.

**1st Option** You can use media Queries

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

<style>
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

@media(max-width: 640px){
  #myVideo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

**2nd Option** set `width: 100%` instead of `min-width: 100%`

```html
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

<style>
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

**3rd Option** Add wrapper for video tag and handle the responsive

```html
<div class="video-Wrapper">
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<style>
.video-Wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}

#myVideo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way is to give your video width as a percentage. This means the width of the video will be the % of the container it is in.

Please check the code below. (I have used a division instead of a video)

```html
<div>12345</div>

<style>
div{
  width:80%;
  height:300px;
  background:#dadada;
}
</style>
```

If you want dfferent css properties at different width o the body then you should use the `@media` query. Check this for more on `@media` queries. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

U can also use vh and vw tags instead of percentages. So that ur video adjusts according to the viewport.

Comment: You can post your reply as a comment, not as a answer.