# Video height max to screen height

Tags: html, responsive

How can we restrict a video height maximum to users screen height in angular? Video height should not be increase screen height. I tried to add some css but no success.

```
<video style="width: 100%; max-height: 90vh;" #myVideoId autoplay></video>
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796799/fully-responsive-html5-video

Answer (score 0):

You could try with height:90vh; max-height:90vh both

Answer (score 0):

use `100vh` which stands for view height instead of `100%` that takes the height of its parent.