# why parent element has additional space

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Hi I have svg rectangle within the div element. I have set the rect element height as 300. while checking the parent element (div) height has been shown as 304 why?

```
<div>
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <rect width="300" height="300" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>

 </div>
```

Sample Link: http://jsfiddle.net/mkn9t627/7/

[image]

Comment: Does it have any additional styling from CSS? Like borders or padding?

Comment: @MarkHünermundJensen no sample added

Comment: @MarkHünermundJensen  http://jsfiddle.net/mkn9t627/7/

Answer (score 2):

There are spaces between your opening and closing tags. Set the font-size of the parent to 0 and it will show 300px in the inspector.

```css
div {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="300" height="300">
  <rect width="300" height="300" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: ok but if i have a text inside the div mean in your scenario the text wont display.

Comment: If you define 300px on the div it will listen to it. I understand maybe there's a more general question, but that at least seems to fix the standing issue

Comment: That's true Akbar, unless you put that text in an element and set the font-size on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `display: block` for svg element because by default it's inline. Here is a good answer for your question: [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600393/there-is-a-4px-gap-below-canvas-video-audio-elements-in-html5)

Comment: You could say that the svg element defaults to `display: inline` and include the link as a reference.