# React component, space below in-line element

Tags: css

I have, in the example below, I have a red element inside of which is a pale green inline-block element. The green element is 100% in width and I'd expect it to fully cover the red element, no red showing. But as you can see, it sets 2-3 pixels above the bottom of its container. I've been staring at it for a while but I can't see what the problem is. I can see no whitespace in the browser inspector. I'm stumped, help appreciated.

```
class DaisyTest extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super( props )
    }

    render() {

        return      <div style={{ width: '300px', backgroundColor: '#f00' }}>
                        <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '200px', display: 'inline-block', backgroundColor: '#efe', }}></div>
                    </div>

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: very annoying indeed, see also [There is a 4px gap below canvas/video/audio elements in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8600393/1176601) - solution is to use `display: block` or flex or whatever, but I couldn't find an explanation WHY it happens yet

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ suggests that the reason for the space is space from source code (between parent `<div>` and child `<div>` there are newlines an indentation in the code, which is rendered in HTML as single space by default, which creates a non-zero line height)

Comment: Normally, yes, that's what I'd look for but I checked in the browser inspector and it shows no white space. I also tried putting the elements together on a single line, no indents, no space. It still does it.

Comment: ah, well, that seems to suggest that the inline-block element itself is perceived similar to a character of text, which triggers a display of non-zero `line-height` (perhaps similar to the space below letter `a` which is needed for characters like `p`)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put any elements to parent div except the nested one, just add attribute `lineHeight` and set it to zero, then set it to `1em` in child div

```
class DaisyTest extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super( props )
    }

    render() {

        return      <div style={{ width: '300px', backgroundColor: '#f00', lineHeight: '0' }}>
                        <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '200px', display: 'inline-block', backgroundColor: '#efe', lineHeight: '1em' }}></div>
                    </div>

    }
}
```